# I have a query that do 2 LEFT JOINs and 1 GROUP BY but I get missing results:

Tags: ms-access

The following query should return around 1159 results but only returns around 880 results;
If I only JOIN the "c" width "mm" I still get the 1159 results. Only when all 3 tables I get 880 results. I also used with no luck: RIGHT JOIN, RIGHT OUTER JOIN, LEFT OUTER JOIN, INNER JOIN. I tried with "()" and without "()" in the JOIN sintax no luck too.

Any help is appreciated

```
SELECT c.ccod, c.cetcm, c.cdscr, c.cpcul, c.cdent, mm.amexi,

Sum(CASE WHEN m.mcdmv=11 THEN m.mqtd END),

Sum(CASE WHEN m.mcdmv=2 THEN m.mqtd END),

Sum(CASE WHEN m.mcdmv=13 THEN m.mqtd END),
Sum(CASE WHEN m.mcdmv=14 THEN m.mqtd END),

MAX(CASE WHEN m.mcdmv=82 THEN m.mdata END)



FROM 
(zzz.ccc c 
LEFT JOIN zzz.mmmm mm ON c.crnp = mm.arncd)
LEFT JOIN zzz.mm m ON m.mrncd = c.crnp



WHERE 
((c.cetcm='xcd') OR
(c.cetcm='ewfwe') OR
(c.cetcm='fewfew') OR
(c.cetcm='fewf')) AND

(m.MDATA Between 20100101 And 20110406) AND

((m.mcdmv=11) OR 
(m.mcdmv=12) OR 
(m.mcdmv=13) OR 
(m.mcdmv=14)) AND

(mm.aarm=1)


GROUP BY c.ccod, c.cetcm, c.cdscr, c.cpcul, c.cdent, mm.amexi

ORDER BY c.ccod
```

Comment: Giving us a row count wont help.  If you told me its supposed to return 7k rows, why do I care? And What is up with the table / field names. `GROUP BY` the most misunderstood TSQL Syntax.

Comment: You need to remember that rows preserved because of the `OUTER` Join will have `NULL` values for the columns in `m` and `mm`. Your `WHERE` clause then eliminates these rows.

Comment: @Totty - So if you comment out the Where clause entirely you still do not get the results you want? What about commenting out section by section of the Where clause? You need to break these problems down into smaller part to isolate the problem.

Comment: SO how do I manage the NULL values in this case?

Comment: @Totty - In most RDBMSs you would add the filter condition into the `ON` clause. Can't remember if Access allows that.

Comment: @Totty - Either check for Is Null in anything the filters against the Left Joined tables or put the criteria in the ON clause

Comment: IF I comment out the m.mcdmv=11,12,13,14 AND the m.MDATA Between... I get all I need.

Comment: @Martin - You can. You just cannot then view that type of the query in the QBE.

Comment: @Thomas - How do I make the check for IS Null in this case? thx

Answer (score 2, accepted):

As has been suggested, you need to move the criteria against the tables in the Left Joins into their respective ON clauses:

```
SELECT c.ccod, c.cetcm, c.cdscr, c.cpcul, c.cdent, mm.amexi
    , Sum(CASE WHEN m.mcdmv=11 THEN m.mqtd END) As Total11
    , Sum(CASE WHEN m.mcdmv=12 THEN m.mqtd END) As Total12
    , Sum(CASE WHEN m.mcdmv=13 THEN m.mqtd END) As Total13
    , Sum(CASE WHEN m.mcdmv=14 THEN m.mqtd END) As Total14
    , MAX(CASE WHEN m.mcdmv=82 THEN m.mdata END) As Max82
FROM (zzz.ccc c 
    LEFT JOIN zzz.mmmm mm 
        ON (c.crnp = mm.arncd
        And m.aarm = 1))
    LEFT JOIN zzz.mm m 
        ON (m.mrncd = c.crnp
            And m.mcdmv In(11,12,13,14,82)
            And m.MDATA Between #20100101# And #20110406#)
WHERE c.cetcm In('xcd','ewfwe','fewfew','fewf')
GROUP BY c.ccod, c.cetcm, c.cdscr, c.cpcul, c.cdent, mm.amexi
ORDER BY c.ccod
```

In addition, I've made use of the IN function which lets you pass a series of values. Btw, Access will likely also balk at not having column aliases for the columns aggregate functions. Here I've just used something simple.

Comment: thanks that worked.. Now it looks like I have too much records.. let me check better!

Comment: The "As Toatal11" and the other As, doesnt appear to change my cols names in the results... :s

Comment: @Totty - Access might want those wrapped in square brackets. E.g. "As [Total11]"

Comment: now I have a problem. I used Microsoft query and not access. Now im using access and if I use "AND" after the "ON" ("...And m.aarm=1") it just crashes!?

Comment: @Totty - You may be running into a different issue. Sometimes it is possible to make a query against Access (Jet) that technically should work but Jet cries uncle via an unrelated error or a crash. It is one of the "fantastic" "features" of Jet. To know if that is the case, I would try stripping out the second join and where clause (and related Select clause entries) and then one-by-one add the elements back in to see where it crashes.

Comment: @Totty - MS Access is actually two products in one. The database engine itself is called Jet (I'm talking about MDB files now. The ACCDB introduced with Access 2007 is its own format) and can be used without MS Access. All kinds of development environments and languages are able to read and write to MDB databases. MS Access is a form and report development tool that is tailored for working with Jet databases.